# How do you conditionally type between a function and an instance of a class?

Tags: typescript

I have this conditional utility type:

```
export type ContextOf<Instance> =
  Instance extends (...args: never[]) => unknown
  ? never
  : Instance
```

### Update 3

[Updated TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2NQwPIBmAPAJKYDOMAhpgMbAB8cAvAFBxxmU31y7CYAJuTgAVABYBLcqOTAiNRA3Yc4Afk4VqdYCo4AuOJmAA3YFFatQkWHEnZzBKrzQAbKuXKktPRnADeKsYA7nAAFAB0UVRQAObkhgCumADWmBDBmADaALoAlIZc2vQA3KwAvpZIKHAAgnHkhEQA0u6eTMxwrR4i-EIiAEIe8vYE5nUNTBr18XCGxmZQZQD0ywhyE-FN3e0sXW29IDj9cEPk8opT+z1ZAOQx8bc5c0am5mWstAenw0Qz5ExAhxBMAvjFUA8EptyB8OLQsJQoIlaDBoGEwIkAEauSS0OAgeaJAC2mPMeQClRU3BguLgBCgECJRAAyli3D0+EcBMJ0AciGd5Mk0hlMAwxWE9AgpFCJNJZCgWWyDgwADSSmDiIWGMLk5hMf5NVmY9ntFQFTTcHTy+RGk0A2Fwam0+mMxXG759Hl2-m-IXpTJilXoBHE8adP0ihgS1RS6SGWUyORuu2qyXwhxHQwQTEAK1BMDVMY1WvCuv1DUNSp6yg45qKvmtyeVDqdeJdTNtHq5J29AqIEYDquDFFDUD2A9F0dUGrjYmljc71cLqnTOCOeCgEhL2bzKLgAB9wjqWOWtsRF+08suOMXUhuAKpCYAEezAQRqJJPl-GQQHo9l6FK3das8jNQofCtJMLwBAJJSgYAYESKBMFeUIwhnEQPDgRQ8mPLD60ghVoIYMoOEqSkwU8OAAFlEDtTljh5Pt-DpCAIEMRF7FiOBykBFRxGAVxXAgPZbg1cxgFuMpKVou0InbMJjz1cIWIINjDFuAShJE8T4NuHi8jyFY1gAARgcgAFprHzKyoAZCxZIOeSGSJRSALCFjMRiDStOEqUJP08pDOMuAzMs6yUVs+zWEcnpnMZNyTxUgyjNYVZQvMqzwBs8xotizx4tcgAmVKrHAaB4EokRmUZYA8F0+igXxPZ8vIQr0OlIMlKYDzWPYuBNMEvzdMklLpNYIA)

By ignoring `ContextOf` entirely, and changing the signature of my function in this way:

```
  class Base<Args> {
    declare args: Args;

    constructor(public x: number) {}

    static from<SubClass extends Class<Base<unknown>>>(
      this: ThisType<SubClass>,
      thunk: () => ArgsOf<SubClass>
    ): InstanceType<SubClass>;

    static from<SubClass extends Class<Base<unknown>>, Consumer = unknown>(
      this: ThisType<SubClass>,
-     context: ContextOf<Consumer>
+     context: object,
      // getting rid of this `?` helped the most.
-     thunk?: () => ArgsOf<SubClass>
+     thunk: () => ArgsOf<SubClass>    
    ): InstanceType<SubClass>;

    static from<SubClass extends Class<Base<unknown>>, Consumer = unknown>(
      this: ThisType<SubClass>,
-     contextOrThunk: ContextOf<Consumer> | (() => ArgsOf<SubClass>),
+     contextOrThunk: object | (() => ArgsOf<SubClass>),
      thunkOrUndefined?: undefined | (() => ArgsOf<SubClass>)
    ): InstanceType<SubClass> {
      return new (this as any)() as InstanceType<SubClass>;
    }
  }
```

I now only have a problem with `ArgsOf`, where the generic type is not inferred.

```
type ArgsOf<Klass> = Klass extends Base<infer Args> ? Args : never;
```

Tho, it seems if I remove the `ThisType` on the `this` arg in these functions, the inference then works -- but then a different error occurs.

### Update 2

[Updated TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2NQwPIBmAPAJKYDOMAhpgMbAB8cAvAFBxxmU31y7CYAJuTgAKAHSSqUAObkAXHEzAAbsCgBtALoBKFkwAqACwCW5A8mBEaiBuw5wA-EtXr7HRcbMWUpCtTpGVlZQSFg4E2x1AipeNAAbKnJyP25ApgBve2UAdzFJcWk5RQBXTABrTAgczG0dRS4A+gBuVgBfYKQUOABBWXJCIgBpROSmZjgRpJF+IREAISSrSIJ1Xv6mZz65OEVlNShWgHojhEt1uUGpsZZJ0ZmQHDm4RfIrG0276Y0AciLyH5aXYuA6tVi0e4vJZEbbkTL2QTACHSVD-RSwsEcWhYShQEq0GDQURgEoAI3iJlocBAexKAFtSeo9BkOvZuDBKXACFAIHSiABlMkJaZ8R4CYToe5EV5WMqVaqYBhK0TuBCmBRwQWk4XJAA0qpgRjlilEemYTFhgy1Orh2ns9U4-h4wB8Vmt9wYmLg7M53N5AqFkNmEpt0uhcqqNSVusdaV4EwjCoYKocarMind031qexUUeigwefwxEazoY2YchrljhNZot-Stgemdg4DtLgVdAe1Hq9Pqpfr5meSoqeIalMqIiaj5djTVQCYqkcVKcr6ozTb1qtzOEeeCgxmN6CwO+LqTnTAAPmJTfoLgNiEO4ToKxwqxU9wBVITAAiRYCCGs4DKRFf2UQQ4CvUQb3NO9G27ZsdHtBonQ7SwuxteFUygYAYBKKBMBcPJDTMG8klnZ1O0fT17A6VlkWHABZRAbRHcUFmhDIuQgCBFFxSIZDgNpMLgIxgHieIIFuH5DXUYAflaVkmJtcQBygusxE4ghuMUH5RPEySZOwn5BJ0HRjlOAABGByAAWlCJEYDsqAeSgVglPuFSeTpNTb1+UwfhjaTRKM3RzLgKzbPsgknJctzmI81ToKYPyTACuAgtkwEzOCUJoHgeiRH5XlgDwQyWKyDgQFudzpk83lRGI8gYySjSuJ49K9IktVMpM7KOiAA) -- looks like my current problem is around specifying a correct `this` type for static inheritance.

Current util implementation:

```
export type ContextOf<Instance> =
  Instance extends (...args: never[]) => ThisType<any>
    ? never
    : ThisType<Instance>
```

### Update

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2NQwPIBmAPAJKYDOMAhpgMbAB8cAvAFBxxmU31y7CYAJuTgAKAHSSqUAObkAXHEzAAbsCgBtALoBKFkwCumANaYIAd0zsOcAPxLV66x0VdqdYK1ahIsOAEtsdQIqXjQAGypyclIKd3omAG9rZXMxSXFpOUUjUwtMbR1XOJ5gAG5WAF8vWkjouAAhKOAiAEFZciTrQWBa6VQshTh2uQrrbhh-WjgCKAgAWyIAZQMAIwiokX4hEQ3ooibyFtyzSwZz0WcEAAt-IZX1uvIAGiuYa9zFUT1mQxNTgpaaxFTglDwAFWQLQee06Yw4EymMzmixhTz4IBwO3QTwOzSIJ3y52eoO4HhYcESlQYlxsNzuijRm1edNoWBwmMUGCCmMIsTJCRZNneuVsXx+fzylm0wOKAuAkJQyzWsIY8JsiOmswWysemwxWOEOM2eKOBP+RIYJLcpQpVJpb1u9xVTyFHDZPPwUHBHxMXPZuD5No8TAAPmJvvo4ITpbo3TdcngoABVITAAiBYCCMXRtMZ5SCODh0SR365qWAnSy0nxBVQ3WqylXKDAGAGKCYBxpd53SNRGulRXQl2bNXWarVVh9eoAWUQsINAiNhxaiRmEAgikoUECMjg1KbHGuwHC4QgFIA5O91MALxVJ3PYeJtfMSxK4BoL7cLySr8eWxeugVI+TzPiib5Rp+36-teAFAV4PjQPA04iEsCzAHgsELskHAgBSIGbGBCyiD2LxiO+UH+D+cB-jegE6PerBAA) (and bonus: [Hard Mode](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.0-beta#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEB2NQwPIBmAPAJKYDOMAhpgMbAB8cAvAFBxxmU31y7CYAJuTgAKAHSSqUAObkAXHEzAAbsCgBtALoBKFkwCumANaYIAd0zsOcAPxLV66x0UAVABYBLcq+TBSFNR0jKysoJCwcJ7Y6gRUvGgANlTk5AHcwUwA3tbK5mKS4tJyikamFpjaOopcQfQA3KwAvqFIKHAAgrLkhEQA0smpTMxwAyki-EIiAEIp-tEE6p3dTPZdcnCKympQjQD0ewh+y3K9Y0Mso4MTIDhTcLPk-jSIq1fjGgDkxeSfWpsOHaNVi0a4POZEdbkbLWQTAUHSVA-RRQ4EcbgwTy0OAEKAQAC2RAAygYAEZJcZ8W4CYToa5ER7+MpmSwMNmiZwILwKOAk8nXAA0nJg7jKilEemYTChvT5FKG2ms1U4gR4wF8KGJZPl0LRcAxWJxeMJcrBk1pOoZEOZFTZApVGV4IyyTQYHJsXO8ilN4yFHtoWBwt0UGBit16tTVDD9NhFZVs4sl0u6su11wYSpqquCGv8PqGeoN2NxBK1-Mp5pElsZRBtrOjDrqqGdrvdse53rTvs5AbD+CgHjF6EDuAj2foTAAPmIJfoTj1iPnoToYxw4yY8FAAKpCYAEaLAQQJuBGOH75SCODT0SzqXz1PloY6TONtW5ss6mEeqDAGAGKCYA4+Qit4s4pK+OZ+B+6aNBwLQtCCYIALKIDqVJ3LSNZZDiEAQIolBQNEMhwK6cA5Bw7jAIkiQQJcnwiuowCfI0CEoTq4glviN5JmI2EELhiifJR1G0QxP6fCROg6PshwAAIwOQAC04TwjAylQHiUCsGx1wcca3Fzl8XifPa9GUeJugyXA8lKSptBqeomnaahumcQZd5GZ4JlwGZjF-NJoThNA8AIqkvIEsAeBiWh5FwCAlw6eMekEqIIHkPat5MKIfECT5wk0VyfmSQFLRAA)) -- doesn't use `expect-type`, so we can focus on the TypeScript bits and not worry about *maybe* issues with `expect-type`

The code from the playground:

```
export type ContextOf<Instance> =
  Instance extends (...args: never[]) => unknown
    ? never
    : Instance

export interface Class<Instance> {
  new (...args: unknown[]): Instance;
}

class Base<Args> {
  declare args: Args;

  static from<SubClass extends Class<Base<unknown>>>(
    this: SubClass,
    thunk: () => unknown[]
  ): InstanceType<SubClass>;

  static from<SubClass extends Class<Base<unknown>>, Instance = {}>(
    this: SubClass,
    context: ContextOf<Instance>,
    thunk?: () => unknown[]
  ): InstanceType<SubClass>;

  static from<SubClass extends Class<Base<unknown>>, Instance = {}>(
    this: SubClass,
    contextOrThunk: ContextOf<Instance> | (() => unknown[]),
    thunkOrUndefined?: undefined | (() => unknown[])
  ): InstanceType<SubClass> {
    return new this() as InstanceType<SubClass>;
  }
}

class MyClass extends Base<{ foo: string }> {
  hello = 'there';
}

MyClass.from(() => ['hi', 'there']);
MyClass.from(() => ['hi', 'there']);

export class SomeOtherClass {
  x = MyClass.from(this, () => ['hi', 'there']);
//^- error1        ^ error2
}
```

where `error1` is:

```
'x' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.(7022)
```

and `error2` is:

```
Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ContextOf<this>'.
  Type 'SomeOtherClass' is not assignable to type 'ContextOf<this>'.(2345)
```

---

### Original Question

and these tests, using [`expect-type`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expect-type)

```
import { expectTypeOf } from 'expect-type';

import type { ContextOf } from 'place where the above utility type is defined';

class A {
  a = 1;
}

expectTypeOf<ContextOf<A>>().toEqualTypeOf<A>();
expectTypeOf<ContextOf<() => ({ foo: number })>>().toEqualTypeOf<never>();

export class B {
  constructor() {
    let x = this;
    expectTypeOf<ContextOf<typeof x>>().toEqualTypeOf<typeof x>();
    // ^ this whole line has a red squiggle with the below error
  }

  foo(this: B) {
    let x = this;
    return expectTypeOf<ContextOf<typeof x>>().toEqualTypeOf<typeof x>();
  }
}
```

The error at the annotated line:

```
Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MismatchArgs<And<[Extends<DeepBrand<ContextOf<this>>, DeepBrand<this>>, Extends<DeepBrand<this>, DeepBrand<ContextOf<this>>>]>, true>'.
```

But more importantly, the hover / signature inspection shows this:

```
(property) ExpectTypeOf<ContextOf<this>, true>.toEqualTypeOf: <this>(...MISMATCH: MismatchArgs<And<[Extends<DeepBrand<ContextOf<this>>, DeepBrand<this>>, Extends<DeepBrand<this>, DeepBrand<ContextOf<this>>>]>, true>) => true (+1 overload)
```

I get the same error when I change `foo`, the method, to a getter, which can't have a `this` arg:

```
  get foo(): unknown {
    let x = this;
    return expectTypeOf<ContextOf<typeof x>>().toEqualTypeOf<typeof x>();
  }
```

```
Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MismatchArgs<And<[Extends<DeepBrand<ContextOf<this>>, DeepBrand<this>>, Extends<DeepBrand<this>, DeepBrand<ContextOf<this>>>]>, true>'.
```

(But again more importantly, the hover / signature inspection shows this:)

```
(property) ExpectTypeOf<ContextOf<this>, true>.toEqualTypeOf: <this>(...MISMATCH: MismatchArgs<And<[Extends<DeepBrand<ContextOf<this>>, DeepBrand<this>>, Extends<DeepBrand<this>, DeepBrand<ContextOf<this>>>]>, true>) => true (+1 overload)
```

I think these errors *may* make sense because the class, `B` is empty, and can't be differentiated from any other class.
So I add a property to it:

```
export class B {
  b = 'b';
```

and then the errors (and hovers) I get (still at the same locations / lines) are the exact same as the above.

So, ultimately my question is:

- How can I tell the difference between an Instance Type and a function?
  And if that's not possible, how can I tell the difference between a function which receives no args, and an Instance type?

Comment: I think you want to use `.toMatchTypeOf` not `.toEqualTypeOf`. That link you have contains some examples of this. Scroll about a quarter of the way down

Comment: Your `ContextOf` type here doesn't have much to do with it. If you try to match the `this` type in the constructor at all, it doesn't seem to like that. https://tsplay.dev/w61qYW. Though it does work if you use the classname directly. https://tsplay.dev/WP9Jqw. Wish I could tell you why, though.

Comment: Yeah, i've noticed that too, and also don't know why. For the library i'm writing, i do need to support receiving a caller's 'this' tho

Comment: I opened https://github.com/mmkal/ts/issues/261 because... this might be a bug in expect-type?

Comment: Should someone have familiarity with expect-type to work on this question? If so, then I guess I'll depart.  If *not*, is there a way to ask this question without reference to it?  I think the issue might be related to TypeScript's general inability to verify assignability to a generic conditional type, and the [`this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) acts like a generic type parameter.  But I can't wade through whatever `DeepBrand` and `MismatchArgs` are in order to know for sure. (If you reply to me, pls @jcalz mention me or I won't be notified)

Comment: ultimately my goal has nothing to do with expect-type, but I don't know of another way of asserting / testing type equality / matching -- I can add whatever would be most helpful to the question -- I just am not sure would would be most helpful atm.

Comment: I have an idea, I'll make a new TS Playground

Comment: updated my example -- it's... a bit hairy, but I don't yet know of a more minimal reproduction, as I worry in boiling it down more, I'll miss out on key interactions between the types -- and this is pretty close to my real-world example where the errors are the exact same as the library I'm working on

Comment: I think the problem is that `this` is actually a different type from whatever class it's supposed to reference? For example, inside a class `Foo`, the types `this` and `Foo` are actually different (not in structure, but behaviorally and interactions).

Comment: makes sense -- how would I resolve that though for my overloaded function when it seems that `ThisType` seems to match `() => Args`?

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbQKBN) what you wanted?